# Detecting touch event on Android devices with different density

Tags: android

How to detect touch coordinates independently display size? Detect the same point of touch event on different devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The touch events will always return the x,y coordinates of the pixels. In case you want them in percentage, you will have to do it programmatically.  You need to get the screen size of the device and then divide accordingly to get the percent.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

**Get them in percentages**

```
int percentageX= (int)((x*100)/width)
int percentageY= (int)((y*100)/height)
```